# Finding a subset of fixed size of a graphs vertex set that minimizes 'surface area'. AKA finding min cut for fixed partition size.

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, reference-request, algorithms, discrete-optimization

Let $G$ be a graph with vertex set $V$ and $n$ a fixed integer. I want to find a set $S\subseteq V$ with $|S|=n$ that minimizes the 'surface area' of $S$, surface area being the number of edges between a vertex in $S$ and a vertex in $V-S$. I would like to know if this problem has a name, if it has been studied before, and if so, where I can find out more about it. This problem is a variation on the [min cut problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_cut) however the wikipeida page doesn't mention this particular variation that requires a fixed size for the partition.

Comment: this can be solved with mixed integer optimization

Comment: could you explain how one would express this as a mixed integer optimization problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> could you explain how one would express this as a mixed integer optimization problem?

Let $x_i \in \{0,1\}$ be the decision variable that indicates if vertex $i$ is in $S$, and $y_e \in \{0,1\}$ be the decision variable that indicates if edge $e$ connects a vertex in $S$ with a vertex in $V\setminus S$.

\begin{align}
\min \quad & \sum_{e \in E} y_e \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & y_e \geq x_i-x_j \quad \forall e \in E, \; \forall (i,j)\in e^2 \; (i\neq j)\\
& \sum_{i \in V} x_i=n \\
& x_i \in \{0,1\}, y_e \geq 0
\end{align}
Let me explain the second constraint: for edge $\{1,2\}$ it sets $y_{\{1,2\}}$ to the absolute difference between $x_1$ and $x_2$ (via $y_{\{1,2\}} \geq x_1 - x_2$ and $y_{\{1,2\}} \geq x_2 - x_1$).